# Enumerated type as a static variable in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, enums, static-members

I need a static variable which holds an enumerated type to be accessed and changed by other classes. Currently I can access its value, but when I try to change it, the new value is not stored. The class it's declared in is not instantiated.

This is the enum declaration:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, weaponType) {
    single, dual
};
```

I have a static getter and setter declared in the .h file:

```
+(weaponType)shipWeaponType;
+(void)setShipWeaponType:(int)aType;
```

In the .m file I have a static variable

```
static weaponType shipWeaponType;
```

And the getter and setter implemented as follows:

```
+ (weaponType)shipWeaponType {
    return shipWeaponType;
}
+ (void)setShipWeaponType:(int)aType {
    shipWeaponType = aType;
}
```

`shipWeaponType` always returns 0. I have tried having `setShipWeaponType` require an actual enum type rather than an int, but it makes no difference.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I have tried your code and got 1 as returned result from the first attempt. You must be having some simple mistake somewhere. The code you've adduced works well

Comment: My Nil-Sense is tingling.

Comment: @Chuck but these are class methods. a class cannot be nil

Comment: @AndreyChernukha: A variable that you think points to a class can be nil. It's true that ending up with a nil reference to a class requires some unusual choices, but this is already kind of a weird design, and it is clear that *something* strange is going on here that (as reported) happens to work exactly like a null reference.

Comment: @Chuck I don't think so; I have other static variables in this class implemented in the same way -- ints, floats, and a Boolean -- which all work fine.

Comment: @user2576824: Given that nobody can reproduce this issue from the code you've provided here, going to need to provide a better code example that people *can* use if you want anyone to tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're just missing something obvious, as what you have appears as though it should work. I just quickly did a test in a single class inside the default sprite kit project since I had it open, and it worked. Here's what it looks like:

```
//=======  .h ==========
typedef NS_ENUM(int, testEnumType){
    nullType,
    oneType,
    twoType,
    initType,

};

@interface MyScene : SKScene

+(void)setStaticVar:(int)var;
+(testEnumType)getStaticVar;

//========= .m ==============
static testEnumType theStaticVar = initType;

@implementation MyScene

+(void)setStaticVar:(int)var
{
    theStaticVar = var;
}

+(testEnumType)getStaticVar
{
    return theStaticVar;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [MyScene setStaticVar:oneType];
    NSLog(@"the var: %i", [MyScene getStaticVar]); //result is the var: 1

}
```

Comment: The setter appears to assign the value in-method, but when the variable is accessed again it has reverted back to 0. I set it like this: `[GameAdmin setShipWeaponType:dual];` -- the same as yours, so I don't understand why mine doesn't work.

Comment: First, when you declare the static variable, set it to something other than 0, that will help you understand if you are looking at some obscure nil reference to it, or whether the value is actually reverting. But I'll check your use case, just to make sure I'm not missing something. EDIT - nope, everything works in all cases. You're either pointing to a nil reference to a class, or you're setting the value somewhere else, or not setting it like you think you are. Make sure you NSLog at every step.

Comment: I figured it out with some NSLogs. The class I was accessing the variable from loaded from CCB before the class I was using to set the variable had loaded from CCB. Thanks for your help :)